# are REST api available for Azure active directory domain services?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am writing a SaaS application to monitor set of azure services. One of them is Azure AAD Domain services but I couldn't find any REST api .

Is there any API available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any Graph API for the AD DS.
But what is it you are trying to monitor? If you wish to monitor what is happening in the Azure AD then there is a Graph for that as well as [Graph tools for reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-api-getting-started-azure-portal).

Else it is possible to talk to the Azure AD DS through LDAP. But then again it all depends on what sort of information you are trying to get.